# Changing values of an array in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have an Array:

```
int[] arr = {-15, -23, -34, -22, 2};
```

I am trying to do an if statement, if values are below 0, then the array value changes to -1. If the values are above 0 the array values are changed to 1.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] swap;
        int[] arr = {-15, -23, -34, -22, 2};
        swap = arr;
        
        
         for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
             System.out.println(arr[x]+swap[x]);
         }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // System.out.println(arr[i]);
            if (arr[i] < 0) {
                arr[i] = -1;
                System.out.println("Oringinal value "+swap[i] + " Error Code: " + arr[i]);
            }
            if (arr[i] > 0) {
                arr[i] = 1;
                System.out.println("Oringinal value "+swap[i] + " Error Code: " + arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

My current code is above.

The objective is to print the original array value with the changed "error code".

However the print out is retuning the same value with the original value.

```
Oringinal value -1 Error Code: -1
Oringinal value -1 Error Code: -1
Oringinal value -1 Error Code: -1
Oringinal value -1 Error Code: -1
Oringinal value 1 Error Code: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the declaration of the `swap`-Array.

Comment: `int[] swap = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);`

Comment: We don't know what `swap` is, but you see the new value of `arr[i]` simply because you set it prior to printing it.

Comment: changed the code above

Comment: Use @IłyaBursov's suggestion, or make a copy in the loop itself. `swap=arr` does not make a copy of the elements of the array, this way `arr` and `swap` are two names for a single array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] swap;
int[] arr = {-15, -23, -34, -22, 2};
swap = arr;
```

With the last command, you are not copying the array, but assigning a reference to the same array in `arr` to the `swap` variable. As a result, any change on `arr` will be reflected on `swap`.

In order to clone the array and persist the original values, you could initialize it like this, creating a deep-copy:

```
int[] swap = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
```

As noted by ***Arvind***, you can also call `arr.clone()` on `arr` to create a shallow copy:

```
int[] swap = arr.clone();
```

*Shallow copies on primitive arrays don't have the side effects that Objects (excluding Strings) do here.*

Answer (score 1):

> `int[] arr = {-15, -23, -34, -22, 2};`

`arr` is a reference. It currently points at that array; consider the array treasure, and `arr` the map that can find it.

`int[] swap = arr;`

This makes a new treasuremap, which is pointing at the exact same treasure.

`arr[i] = 1;`

This follows the `arr` map to find the X, digs down, opens the treasure chest, and does a bunch of stuff there. `swap`, given that it's a different map but one that leads to the exact same treasure, now has the property that if you follow that one, you'll find the same changes. There is, after all, only one treasure.

The solution is to replicate that treasure. `Arrays.copyOf(arr)` can do it, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The swap must be a deep copy of arr, such as

```
int[] arr = {-15, -23, -34, -22, 2};
int[]swap = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] swap;
int[] arr = {-15, -23, -34, -22, 2};
swap = arr;
```

With this code, you actually saving the reference of the arr array in swap. Which means both names are referencing the same array. So you have to copy the array called arr.

```
int[]swap = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
```